# Confusion about electromagnetic waves?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

I am really confused what are electromagnetic waves in physical sense. I have visited several websites to learn about it, but am suffering to still understand it to its core.

Can someone what does many researchers actually mean when they talk about propagation of electromagnetic waves. Is it the same as propagation of sound waves or something else? Also what does the trough and crest shown in common graph of electromagnetic waves imply in actual sense? Also what does oscillation of electric and magnetic field imply? All these doubts have been disturbing me and would feel helpful of any help.

Comment: Why don't sound waves confuse you as well?

Comment: Please also take a look at [this punctuation guide](https://www.learnenglish.de/punctuation/punctuationtext.html)

Comment: There are many good  question on this topic, try to search on stack exchange!

Answer (score 1):

"Waves" are a particular model that represents some phenomena in the physical world under certain circumstances.  Waves have characteristics like *wavelength* and *frequency* and *speed* which are quantities that can be measured in various ways.  Waves also have behaviors or properties like interference and diffraction.  These are common for all types of waves, electromagnetic or otherwise.

Propagation can be thought of in several ways, but essentially the wave is transmitting energy from point-to-point at a certain speed and strength.  The wave description allows the calculation of the propagation details of each type of wave.

The crest and trough in the electromagnetic case are the strength/magnitude of the electric field or magnetic field vector at that point and time.  If you put a wire at a given location (like a radio antenna), the electrons in that wire will react to the time varying electric field and produce an electrical current which can be amplified in the radio and listened to.

Electromagnetic waves don't require a medium to propagate, but as far as observations of wave behavior as I've described above, it is just like other types of waves.

Again, waves are a model which apply under some circumstances.  In certain cases, for example in explaining the "photoelectric effect," the idea of photons (particles of light) is a more appropriate model etc.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In the classical Maxwellian sense, a changing electric field induces a changing magnetic field ahead of it, which induces a changing electric field ahead of *it*, and so on and so on.  *This explanation is of necessity hand-wavy*, which may be why you're confused.  Particularly because everyone's hand-wavy explanation is going to be different from the next person's.  Unfortunately, to actually be able to really understand this stuff you have to do the math, and to do *that* you need a couple of years of physics or electrical engineering courses, plus some fun* math (electrodynamics don't make sense without partial differential equations).

This is much like how a pressure peak causes gas molecules to move ahead of it, which all pile up into a pressure peak, which causes molecules to move and so on and so on.

At the risk of re-confusing you (assuming the above un-confused you in the least bit), the electric field induces a magnetic field at right angles to itself, which induces an electric field pointing opposite the original and so on and so on.

* Well, fun to me...

Answer (score 1):

What is a wave? A wave is the propagation of a perturbation in a field. (A field in physics is any function of space, for example: temperature, air pressure, etc...)

Why does a wave propagate? When one "disturbs" some point in the field (meaning, giving it an initial condition which is out of equilibrium), the disturbance changes the conditions of the field around. For example, if you increase the air pressure in one point in space, the points around it feel the increased pressure and they want to move, making the pressure there to increase and the pressure in the initial point to decrease. Now, the disturbance is at the points around the initial point, and the process continues. Meaning if someone will map the pressure at every point in space and time he will see the disturbance from equilibrium "moving". This is called a wave. A wave can emerge in every field that satisfies some kinds of equations (which is almost every field).

The most favorable waves in physics and engineering are waves that look like the cosine function (meaning, looks like what one might imagine when thinking about a wave). They have a crest and trough and one can define on them a frequency and wavelength. See the following link [1] to understand what a sound wave that looks like a cosine really means. You can see that in some points the air is moving to the left, at some points to the right. But if you look on its density/pressure you'll see the perturbation moving to the right and it has the form of a cosine, with peaks and troughs.

Now that you understand what a wave is, an electromagnetic wave is the same thing but instead of the field being air density/air pressure, the fields are the electric and magnetic fields. When changing in one place the electric field (by moving electric charges, for example), the points around them will have a change in magnetic and electric field too, which will influence their surroundings and the process will continue. So to your question: if you understand the meaning of a wave in general, an electromagnetic wave is nothing different (just a different field).

[1] http://resource.isvr.soton.ac.uk/spcg/tutorial/tutorial/Tutorial_files/longipatm.gif